# MVVM: Design a ViewModel architecture with aggregated/depending ViewModels

Tags: wpf, mvvm, communication, viewmodel, mediator

The **WPF/MVVM alpha geeks** say:

1 View has 1 ViewModel. Sometimes Multiple Views has 1 ViewModel (using a *Wizard*).

If you regard my image you see 6 colored Views/UserControls.

The YELLOW,GREEN and ORANGE UserControls
are used multiple times in my application.

The pink,blue and red UserControls are used only once.

Questions:

**1.** Should I make them UserControls too? If yes, why if I do not reuse them.

**2.** Assume those are 6 UserControls, should they share the same ViewModel?
OR should each View have its own ViewModel?

A.)
Create Classcode in GREEN 
Send class code to YELLOW

B.)
Select class code in YELLOW
Change current pupil in BLUE

C.)
Select current pupil in BLUE
Change pupil details in RED
Change pupil documents in ORANGE

D.)
Create pupil in PINK
Send pupil to BLUE

E.)... many more

Is that the way to go, firing around data with a Messenger class to keep the relations up to date?

There is a major flaw for me:

I create a PupilViewModel but I do not know in the NewPupilViewModel(PINK) wether a SchoolclassCodeViewModel exists in the YELLOW UserControl so I could add my new PupilViewModel to the BLUE UserControl.

SchoolclassCodeViewModel 1 : N PupilViewModel.

**3.** How would you solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan's approach is pretty much identical to what I was going to suggest.  To answer the specific questions:

1)  I would make them UserControls if there's any complexity to their layout at all.  For one, it's easier to do everything consistently; for another, this makes it easier to play around with the layout of that control in Expression Blend without having to instantiate an entire window.

2)  There's application view model for the entire window.  It contains properties for the views that need them:

```
ObservableCollection<ClassCodeViewModel> ClassCodes
ClassCodeViewModel NewClassCode
ClassCodeViewModel SelectedClassCode
PupilViewModel NewPupil
PupilViewModel SelectedPupil
```

2A) `ClassCodeViewModel` exposes a `CreateCommand` that raises an event when it's executed.  The window view model handles this event and does the appropriate update to `ClassCodes` when it's raised.

2B) The class code view model contains an observable collection of pupil view models.  The  `SelectedItem` property in the `SelectedClassCode` property in the window view model that the `SelectedItem` on the class codes view model is bound to. The blue view is bound to `SelectedClassCode.Pupils`.

2C) Similarly, the window view model contains a `SelectedPupil` property that the `SelectedItem` property of the blue view is bound to.  The red view is bound to `SelectedPupil`.

2D) This is handled the same way that it's handled in 2A:  the pupil view model raises an event and the window view model handles it.

3) The pupil view model contains a boolean `CanCreate` property.  This isn't used in the red view.  The window view model sets `NewPupil.CanCreate` in the setter of `SelectedClassCode`.

You didn't ask, but the orange view is bound to the `Documents` property of `SelectedPupil`, which is probably (depending on what documents actually are) an observable collection of `DocumentViewModel` objects.

Maybe I've been toiling in the fields of MVVM for too long, but this seems extremely straightforward to me.

Comment: Dear Robert, I am right you assume that I use ONE ViewModel for all Views? If yes, than the solution is easy right because I tried that too before, BUT there is a drawback => For the reusable Views I can not reuse the ViewModel_Code I would have to do copy+paste so my code is DOUBLE or even TRIPLE using the DocumentsView UserControl at 3 different places.

Comment: Another big drawback for me having one ViewModel and one View containing the 6 Views is the one View + VM is accessed via a viewmodel locator and the View+ViewModel is created via MEFedMVVM. Thats fine but the 6 Views Inside the One View - which is put in the ContentControl- can`t be created by MEFedMVVM because there are NO 6 ViewMOdels now anymore... so I will lose all visual state in the 6 Views.

Comment: About y 2nd drawback I think I was wrong, because the one ViewModel in the ContentControl - with the one View holding the 6 Views - is created only once and shared so the datacontext all 6 Views are bound to is saved too via Two-way databinding. OK so only the FIRST drawback seems valid to me.

Comment: Seems WinForms with UserControls + a presenter behind it can do it more reusable... just a side notice. A solution COULD be to fire a messenger.notification when the selectedSchoolclass in the YELLOW View is changed but this will never happen, as the NewPupilViewMOdel (PINK) is created AFTER the SchoolclassListViewModel (YELLOW) so nobody registered for the selectedSchoolclassCode. Anyone knows a solution for that?

Comment: I really don't understand any of these comments.  Lose visual state?  MEFed?  Messenger notification?  Register?  The design I outlined doesn't involve any of that.  There's a view model, or a collection of view models, for every view.  Something creates the window view model, and it knows how to create everything else.  It subscribes to events on the objects it creates.  It's very straightforward.

Comment: Sorry Robert for answering that late. I am about to move etc... therefore I was confused too because of too much stress etc... ok now I made MEFedMVVM working with my AdminViewModel where I have the same properties you suggest and my DocumentListViewModel and PupilListViewModel is still used, thats really fine.